# asp net core web api how to use .NET Framework

Tags: .net, dll, asp.net-core-webapi

My server was written in ASP.NET Core Web API and I have dll file which can work only with .NET framework. 
How can I use this dll in my application? 
Please help me. Can I create library with .NET Standard and use it with ASP.NET Core Web API? Will it work?

Comment: Make another server in .NET Framework and use lib by API.

Comment: You can create other project targeting .net framework that uses this .dll, then you can use it.